# Import hotmail friend's emails in asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, hotmail

I am build an application to import my friend list from my hotmail accounts.
I tired to find out exact solution. Most of the links provide solution, but no one is work.
Can any one give me more information about this.

Thanks in advance.

Imad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463989.aspx

Comment: I already go through this i implement the code provided but i am unable to get friend list, it says authentication failed, i have registration key,